# Dynamically creating html element and object associated with it on some event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

1.create a main object which is empty initially 
2.On some event like button clike perform the following.
3.create an element and append that element to the container(html body).
4.call a function that will dynamically create a object for that element.
5.store the element properties like class in the element object.

```js
var main_info = { };
$("button").on("click", function(){
var element = '<div class="class1 class2 class3 class4"></div>';
$("body").append(element);
ele_info(element);
function ele_info(element){
   var info = { };
    info.class_arr = element.classList;
    //how to push info object to main_info object.
   }
 });
```

If i click button 5 times than i will have 5 elements in the body. 
Now if i want to know the properties of say 3rd element how should i select that element and how should i access element object properties?

Comment: Please clarify your question. What is not going to be in sequential order? Button clicks are always performed in sequential order as javascript is single-threaded. Moreover, you have `main_info` with 5 properties with the same name, that is not something that you want to do. And how are you even going to generate it? Your code doesn't suggest anything that would lead to it.

Comment: Now have a look @MatusDubrava. yeah i want to know how should i generate objects and access it.

Answer (score 0):

> 1.create a main object which is empty initially

```
var main_info = [];
```

> 2.On some event like button clike perform the following. 3.create an element and append that element to the container(html body).

```
$("button").on("click", function() {});

var element = "<div>Here we go</div>";
$("body").append(element);
```

> 4.call a function that will dynamically create a object for that element.

```
function ele_info(elem) {}
```

> 5.store the element properties like class in the element object.

```
var info = {};
info.class_arr = $(elem).attr('class').split(/\s+/);
main_info.push(info);
```

Final code will be this

```js
var main_info = [];
$("button").on("click", function() {
  var element = "<div>Here we go</div>";
  $("body").append(element);
  var divs = $("div");
  $(divs[divs.length - 1]).addClass("class1 class2 class3 class4");

  ele_info($("div")[$("div").length - 1]);

  function ele_info(elem) {
    var info = {};
    info.class_arr = $(elem).attr('class').split(/\s+/);
    main_info.push(info);
    console.log(main_info);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <button>add</button>
</body>
```

Also accessing to any element added is like this

```
console.log($("div")[2]);
```

And from array:

```
console.log(main_info[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

1. make `main_info` array, so you can push the info.
2. create elements programmatically like `document.createElement('DIV')`.
3. at the end, store the element class info into `main_info`: `main_info.push(element.classList.value.split(' '))`
4. access the 3rd element's info: `main_info[2]`

code:

```js
var main_info = [];

$("button").on("click", function(){
  var element = document.createElement('button');
  element.classList = 'class1 class2 class3 class4';
  element.innnerHTML = 'ANYTHING';
  main_info.push(element.classList.value.split(' '));
  $("body").append(element);
  console.log(main_info);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>OK</button>
```